# Does the cmath macro INFINITY always works for double?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, infinity, cmath

I'm using the `cmath` macro `INFINITY` with `double` numbers and I've not seen any problem so far: in my experience it has always evaluated to `double` infinity. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x = INFINITY;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // prints "inf" as expected
    return 0;
}
```

But according to [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/INFINITY/), `INFINITY` seems guaranteed to evaluates to infinity only for `float`. Is it always guaranteed to evaluate to infinity for `double` (and `long double`) too?

I know that the C++ standard library `std::numeric_limits` solves this problem but I'm working on an embedded system with limited memory so I would rather use what I already have (`cmath`) than add another header.

Edit: I'm using C++11.

Comment: If your platform implements IEEE 754 properly, you could simply evaluate `1.0 / 0.0` to obtain infinity typed as a double.

Comment: @idclev: That's true, `std::isinf` has a `double` overload, but I don't understand why this would prove that `INFINITY` is always correct for `double`. `std::isinf` and `INFINITY` are two different things after all.

Comment: A float value for infinity will convert to a double value for infinity. Presumably a compiler will be smart enough to do that conversion at compile time.

Comment: @cdhowie That works, but I prefer to be sure of what standard libraries do rather than rely on a trick.

Comment: @Mµvh773 This isn't a "trick." It's how IEEE 754 floating point is _defined to work._

Comment: @cdhowie I agree that your solution is reliable. But writing an arithmetical operation in order to get a special value seems like a trick to me, even if it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Per the C++14 standard:

> 1. A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. The value is unchanged.

-- N4296 [conv.fpprom]

If the value was infinity before promotion to a double, it will remain infinity after promotion.

Comment: I'm not using C++14, but I suppose this is true for C++11 too.

Comment: @Mµvh773 Well, you could always... specify the version you're using in the question.